# Error : "non-fast-forward" GitHub

Tags: github, egit

I'm trying to push some files to a remote repository from Eclipse to GitHub.
but I get this error "rejected push - non-fast-forward".

any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that the remote repository that you're pushing to is ahead of your local one – someone else made other changes.
You need to pull and merge those changes first.